# Express-session defined in one route file not available in app.js Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express-4, express-session

I have issue with express-session in node js and express 4. I set a session variable inside routes/index.js and is not available in app.js.But available on another route file users.js

### routes/index.js

```
var sess;
router.get('/setsession',function(req,res){
    sess=req.session;
    sess.username="safeer"; 
    res.send("hi "+sess.username);
});

router.get('/getsession',function(req,res){
    sess=req.session;
    res.send("hi "+sess.username); //here session value available
});
```

### routes/users.js

```
var sess;
router.get('/session3',function(req,res){
    sess=req.session;
    res.send("hi "+sess.username); // here also session is available
});
```

### app.js

```
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({secret: 'secret',saveUninitialized: true,resave: true}));

var sess;
app.get('/session1',function(req,res){
    sess=req.session;
    res.send("hi "+sess.username); //here session is undefined
});
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

Can anyone give me a solution please. ?

Comment: Is `sess` a global (unscoped) variable? If so, you should expect undefined behaviour. Also, how and where are you declaring the `express-session` middleware?

Comment: sess is defined. not included in code snippet. express-session is defined in app.js. i'll edit code snippet.

Comment: You're declaring `sess` as a module-scoped variable, which means that concurrent requests will overwrite it. It needs to be scoped to each request handler instead.

Comment: we rewrites inside each request handler as sess=req.session; 
req.session matters i think

Comment: Once you start making async calls from within your request handlers, you will run into undefined behaviour because concurrent requests are sharing the same `sess` variable. This most likely isn't causing the problem you're describing here, but I felt it deserved a warning at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you set username in session:

In routes/index.js

```
router.get('/setsession',function(req,res){
       req.session.username="safeer"; 
       res.send("hi "+ req.session.username);
});
```

And in app.js

```
app.get('/session1',function(req,res){
    res.send("hi "+ req.session.username); //get from session. Can be set in variable too
```

});